# Python 3.6. Чем заменить walrus оператор

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Скрипт принимает на вход путь с файлами и сравнивает их между собой по хеш-сумме. Ну а чтобы сильно не грузить оперативную память, принято решение резать файлы на кусочки.

Есть проблема. Walrus. В python 3.8 все отлично, но для python 3.6 работать не будет (3.6 не поддерживает walrus). Чем заменить конструкцию `while chunk := f.read(8192)`?

```
def identical_video_by_hash(file_path):
    
    video_hash_name_dict = {}

    for file in Path(file_path).glob(r"**/*"):
        if file.suffix.casefold() in file_ext:
            with open(video, "rb") as f:
                file_hash = hashlib.md5()
                while chunk := f.read(8192):
                    file_hash.update(chunk)
        video_hash_name_dict[str(file)] = file_hash.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать функцию `iter` с двумя параметрами: с функцией (которая при каждом запросе считывает и возвращает новый блок данных) и признаком окончания итерации (значение, которое должна вернуть функция, переданная в первом параметре, чтобы итерация прекратилась, в документации называется "sentinel" - "стражник"). В данном случае итерация должна прекратиться, когда вернется пустой блок (`b''`). Функция `iter` возвращает итератор, его можно использовать в конструкции `for`.

```
with open(video, "rb") as f:
    file_hash = hashlib.md5()
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8192), b''):
        file_hash.update(chunk)
```

Документация: [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) (там как раз приведен пример для такой задачи)

Comment: Константу размера буфера можно брать из библиотеки `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`. Мелочи, конечно, но уходит магия.

Answer (score 4):

Этот способ допустим?

```
def identical_video_by_hash(video_path):
    video_hash_name_dict = {}

    for video in Path(video_path).glob(r"**/*"):
        if video.suffix.casefold() in video_ext:
            with open(video, "rb") as f:
                file_hash = hashlib.md5()
                while True:
                    chunk = f.read(8192)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    file_hash.update(chunk)
        video_hash_name_dict[str(video)] = file_hash.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Допустимо, так и выглядит в старом стиле считывание с проверкой